# Filtering and summarising data from one dataframe using datetimes from another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering, summary

I am trying to use datetime stamps from one dataframe to filter and summarise data from another dataframe. This is also to be done by a grouping variable (a UserId). Here are some fictional examples of the data I am working with:-

df1

```
df1<-structure(list(UserId = c("6i9Gla", "6i9Gla", "6i9Gla", "6i9Gla", 
"6i9Gla", "6i9Gla", "59hGIY", "59hGIY", "LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", 
"LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", "LzDaPX", 
"o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", 
"o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", 
"o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o0fsPt", "o3wUUC", "o3wUUC", "o3wUUC", 
"gXbJAq", "gXbJAq"), Duration = c(632L, 167L, 868L, 27L, 309L, 
671L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 19L, 81L, 600L, 391L, 615L, 332L, 197L, 168L, 
27L, 836L, 257L, 24L, 555L, 99L, 286L, 387L, 11L, 79L, 181L, 
293L, 126L, 6L, 10L, 1247L, 259L, 11L, 547L, 28L, 19L, 17L, 7L, 
10L), Genre = c("Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", 
"Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", 
"Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", 
"Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", 
"Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", 
"Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", "Sport", 
"Sport"), DateTime_Start = structure(c(1614292441.754, 1614291282.352, 
1614291509.308, 1614288742.042, 1614294373.856, 1614293122.735, 
1614294911.325, 1614289403.922, 1614289358.205, 1614290574.724, 
1614293909.406, 1614295977.859, 1614294049.531, 1614294711.345, 
1614295613.728, 1614294488.27, 1614295400.927, 1614293277.01, 
1614290364.352, 1614293571.4, 1614293873.58, 1614292529.847, 
1614291353.127, 1614296784.14, 1614295424.46, 1614294012.164, 
1614293909.164, 1614292191.902, 1614291777.142, 1614295930.443, 
1614292521.197, 1614291208.605, 1614294092.039, 1614293283.587, 
1614294040.841, 1614296214.851, 1614292701.846, 1614296929.017, 
1614294151.79, 1614292835.834, 1614288948.473), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -41L), class = "data.frame")


head(df1)
  UserId Duration Genre      DateTime_Start
1 6i9Gla      632 Sport 2021-02-25 22:34:01
2 6i9Gla      167 Sport 2021-02-25 22:14:42
3 6i9Gla      868 Sport 2021-02-25 22:18:29
4 6i9Gla       27 Sport 2021-02-25 21:32:22
5 6i9Gla      309 Sport 2021-02-25 23:06:13
6 6i9Gla      671 Sport 2021-02-25 22:45:22
```

df2

```
df2<-structure(list(UserId = c("6i9Gla", "59hGIY", "LzDaPX", "o0fsPt", 
"o3wUUC", "gXbJAq"), OrigTime = structure(c(1614288742.042, 1614289403.922, 
1614289358.205, 1614290364.352, 1614292701.846, 1614288948.473
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), LastTime = structure(c(1614291509.308, 
1614289403.922, 1614290574.724, 1614293909.164, 1614294151.79, 
1614288948.473), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    events_recount = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")


head(df2)

  UserId            OrigTime            LastTime events_recount
1 6i9Gla 2021-02-25 21:32:22 2021-02-25 22:18:29              3
2 59hGIY 2021-02-25 21:43:23 2021-02-25 21:43:23              1
3 LzDaPX 2021-02-25 21:42:38 2021-02-25 22:02:54              2
4 o0fsPt 2021-02-25 21:59:24 2021-02-25 22:58:29             11
5 o3wUUC 2021-02-25 22:38:21 2021-02-25 23:02:31              2
6 gXbJAq 2021-02-25 21:35:48 2021-02-25 21:35:48              1
```

Essentially, I am trying to group by UserId and then filter and summarise the rows in df1 that occur between `OrigTime` and `LastTime` in df2. Here is what I want to summarise between the filtered rows:-

- The total duration (sum the `Duration` column in df1)
- The average duration (mean of the `Duration` column in df1)
- The most watched `Genre` in df1
- How many times did the `Genre` change (I know in this answer, it will be zero, but I need to apply the solution to a larger, more diverse real-world dataset

After this, I would like the output of the filtering and summary to be merged back onto df2.

Any pointers on how to do this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
# Convert df1 and df2 to data.table format
#  keep rownames in column 'rn' and set keys 
setDT(df1, keep.rownames = "rn1")
setDT(df2, keep.rownames = "rn2")
# create an end-dummyvariable in df1
df1[, temp_time := DateTime_Start]
# set keys
setkey(df1, UserId, DateTime_Start, temp_time)
setkey(df2, UserId, OrigTime, LastTime)
# perform overlap join
answer <- foverlaps(df2, df1)
# now you can summarise based on this data.table
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step guide how we could do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Question 1 and 2
sum_mean_Duration <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="UserId") %>% 
  group_by(UserId) %>% 
  mutate(condition = ifelse(between(DateTime_Start, OrigTime, LastTime), 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(condition == 1) %>% 
  summarise(Total_duration = sum(Duration), Mean_duration = mean(Duration)) 


# Question 3 (I added some mock data "Thriller")
Max_watched <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="UserId") %>% 
  group_by(UserId) %>%
  count(Genre) %>% 
  filter(n == max(n))

# Question 4 (I added some mock data "Thriller")
Change_Genre <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="UserId") %>% 
  group_by(UserId) %>% 
  summarise(Change_Genre = n_distinct(Genre)) 

# the single dataframes
sum_mean_Duration
Max_watched
Change_Genre

# Bring them all together with df2
list(df2, sum_mean_Duration, Max_watched, Change_Genre) %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = "UserId")
```

Output:

```
  UserId            OrigTime            LastTime events_recount Total_duration Mean_duration Genre  n Change_Genre
1 6i9Gla 2021-02-25 21:32:22 2021-02-25 22:18:29              3           1062      354.0000 Sport  4            2
2 59hGIY 2021-02-25 21:43:23 2021-02-25 21:43:23              1              8        8.0000 Sport  2            1
3 LzDaPX 2021-02-25 21:42:38 2021-02-25 22:02:54              2             26       13.0000 Sport  9            2
4 o0fsPt 2021-02-25 21:59:24 2021-02-25 22:58:29             11           2599      236.2727 Sport 17            2
5 o3wUUC 2021-02-25 22:38:21 2021-02-25 23:02:31              2             45       22.5000 Sport  3            1
6 gXbJAq 2021-02-25 21:35:48 2021-02-25 21:35:48              1             10       10.0000 Sport  2            1
```

Answer (score 1):

This code may work.

```
change_ftn <- function(x){
  count <- 0
  eval <- 1
  if (length(x) == 1){
    count <- 0
  }
  else {
    for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
      if(eval == 1){
        if(!(x[i] == x[i+1]) ){
          count <- count + 1
          eval <- 0
        }
      } else {
        eval <- 1
      }
    }
  }
  count
}

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, "UserId") %>%
  filter(DateTime_Start > OrigTime, DateTime_Start < LastTime) %>%
  group_by(UserId) %>%
  summarise(UserId = unique(UserId),
            OrigTime = unique(OrigTime),
            LastTime = unique(LastTime),
            events_recount = unique(events_recount),
            sum = sum(Duration),
            mean = mean(Duration),
            max = which.max(table(Genre)) %>% names,
            change = change_ftn(Genre)
         )

  UserId OrigTime            LastTime            events_recount   sum  mean max   change
  <chr>  <dttm>              <dttm>                       <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 6i9Gla 2021-02-25 21:32:22 2021-02-25 22:18:29              3   167  167  Sport      0
2 o0fsPt 2021-02-25 21:59:24 2021-02-25 22:58:29             11  1684  187. Sport      0
```

Comment: I think it is nearly there. The output that you show is what I had in mind, but I would like it to be done for each row in df2. So instead of one line output in this instance (as shown in your solution), I would like the same output but for each user/row within df2. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @RobinTurkington Does that four summarized stuff need to summarized by UserId? If so, I'll edit my code above.

Comment: yes please. Sorry, I should have made that more clearer. Appreciate it if you could amend the code.

Comment: @RobinTurkington I edit my code. I'm sorry that code is pretty not fancy.